# about convection term in the NSE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $u=(u_1(x, y), u_2(x, y))$ be two dimensional vector field and consider the convection term $(u\cdot\nabla) u$ in the NSE. In some books it is usually written in this form, but in some other books or papers it is written as $u\cdot\nabla u$, where ''$\cdot$'' denotes the usual dot product. In order to see this I did the following simple calculations:

$(u\cdot\nabla) u=(u_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+u_2\frac{\partial}{\partial y})(u_1,u_2)=\bigg(u_1\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}+u_2\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}, u_1\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}+u_2\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y}\bigg)=u_1\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+u_2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=(u_1, u_2).(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y})=u\cdot\nabla u$

Q: I wanna make sure whether it is okey or not

Comment: you seem to be using $u$ in two different ways in $u \cdot \nabla u;$ the first one as a vector and the second one as a scalar.

Comment: The way you've introduced $u$, in $u\cdot\nabla u$ the $\cdot$ wouldn't denote a dot product, since to the left of it stands a vector and to the right the divergence of a vector, hence a scalar. It is *not* true that $(u\cdot\nabla)u=u(\nabla\cdot u)$, and that last expression is the only way to make sense of $u\cdot\nabla u$ the way you've introduced $u$.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is essentially correct, but be careful in the second to last equality since $\partial u /\partial x$ and $\partial u / \partial y$ are both vectors, so the term $(\partial u /\partial x, \partial u /\partial y)$ is not really a vector, but a matrix.  In fact, one can also show (using your calculation) that
$$
(u \cdot \nabla) u = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_x u_1 & \partial_y u_1 \\
\partial_x u_2 & \partial_y u_2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 \\ u_2
\end{pmatrix}
= Du u^T
$$
where $D u$ is the Jacobian matrix of partials and $u^T$ is the transpose of the row vector $u$.